# Why does the vector gets expanded in the loop

Tags: r

My requirement is to select a window of size 5 from the 'data' variable and use it in further processing. (please see following code). However, the length of 'sub_data' increases for each iteration. What am I doing wrong?

```
  next_one<-function(data) { 
        for(k in 10:length(data)) {  
          sub_data<-data[k-5:k];
          print(sub_data);   

        }
    }
```

I call the function as follows:

```
dat=read.csv("file name");
attach(dat);
#assume there is a column called 'Value'
next_one(Value);
```

Comment: What are you passing to the function as the `data` argument?

Comment: I added those details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Add parentheses:

`(k-5):k`

Compare

```
20-5:20
#[1] 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

with

```
(20-5):20
#[1] 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

And read `help("Syntax")` to learn about operator precedence.